# Making a div not display until after a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div on the top of the browser and I only want it to appear after a certain amount of time. I have tried hiding it and putting a delay on it showing but because I have a **hover request** it shows straight away once someone hovers over it.

Here is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Johnnyfanta/8xLSa/

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* hide then delay 5 seconds to appear */
    $('#leave').hide().delay(5000).show(); 
    $('#exit_popup').hide();

    $('#leave').hover(function() {
        $('#exit_popup').show();
        $('#lightbox').show();
    });
});
```

When the page loads the id tag is there, but the display is set to none, how can I hide the tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make use of the [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

```
$('#leave').hide();  //or better with CSS...

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#leave').show();
}, 5000);
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/8xLSa/2/)

Comment: Thanks I was going about it the wrong way, that sorted it straight away.

Answer (score 1):

A Simple `setTimeout` is enough, I guess

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("body").append("<div class='test'></div>")
    }, 3000);
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/X8CgL/**